# Implementing REST "fields" query param with Mapstruct

Tags: mapstruct

I am trying to implement REST query param "fields" with Mapstruct. The REST "fields" query param by convention lets you specify as its value a comma separated list of the fields of the entity you want in the response when you are preforming a GET request on an entity. This is opposed to returning all the fields of entity, which is what happens when "fields" query parameter is omitted.

Example:

GET locahost/blah/1
Response {"a":"1", "b":"2", c:"3"}

GET local/blah/1?fields=a,c
Response {"a":"1", "c":"3"}

So what I want Mapstruct to do is only map the bean's fields who's fields' names I specify. Note I need to be able to specify the bean's fields' names I want to map at runtime. Why? The fields I wish to map change from call to call of the GET method.

From what I read in the MapStruct documentation, you can specify what fields to map or not map with annotations. Unfortunately you can't change the annotation value at runtime (It maybe possible through reflection, but it feels should be a better way).

Given what I want to do, does anyone know how I can specify at runtime what fields are mapped?

Or alternately does anyone know a better way of implementing the REST "fields" query param?

I Look forward to reading the responses. If you have any questions or need clarifications just ask .

Regards,

Ben.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thinking about this, I think that it doesn't make sense. As MapStruct generates the mapper classes at build time and therefore can't changing the mapping process at runtime. Is this right?

Comment: That's right, mapstruct generates classes during the compilation